# How to preserve Vaadin ComboBox selection when setting DataProvider?

Tags: combobox, vaadin

`Vaadin 12.0.3`

I have a helper method that returns `ListDataProvider` for Days of the Month. When User changes Month, I recall the helper method and reset `DataProvider` to reflect the new Day range.

```
    filterDay.setDataProvider(IndexViewHelper.getCalendarDaysDataProvider(year, month));
```

The problem is that setting `DataProvider` on `ComboBox` removes currently selected option. To prevent this, I need to do something like this:

```
var currentValue = filterDay.getValue();
filterDay.setDataProvider(IndexViewHelper.getCalendarDaysDataProvider(year, month));
if(currentValue exists in the new list) filterDay.setValue(currentValue);
```

Is there a better way to do this? Basically, I would hope that `setDataProvider()` would not reset currently selected option if that option exists in the newly supplied list.

I know this can get very complex, especially with paging results. I just wanted to ask this on the forum in case there are better ways to deal with the issue.

Comment: Why would it makes sense to keep the same selection if the list changed? The user chose an item which no longer exists.

Comment: Because when User selects February in a Month drop-down, then Day drop-down list changes to 1-28 or 1-29. So if User had selected Day 1 and then makes a Month selection, there's no reason to remove Day 1 selection.

Comment: which month is 1-29? jokes aside, I think your approach is perfectly fine, I would have done the same.